# retrieving the notifications for a given user

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I'm having some serious problems using the facebook graph api: I retrieve the news feed with:

var query = FB.Data.query('SELECT post_id, actor_id, message, FROM stream WHERE filter_key in (SELECT filter_key FROM stream_filter WHERE uid={0} AND type="newsfeed")', response.id);

and it works fine but then when I also try to simply get the notification for the same user with:

var q = FB.Data.query('SELECT notification_id FROM notification WHERE recipient_id={0},response.id);

not only it doesn't even enter the q.wait{} for that query, but also actually seems to stop the fisrt query that is supposed to retrieve the newsfeed and was working fine before

If anybody has any idea of what is going on (I also went through the permissions spec to see if anything was specified for notification retrieval but in vain), I would be very grateful.
Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an apostrophe before the comma.

Your query should read:

```
var q = FB.Data.query('SELECT notification_id FROM notification WHERE recipient_id={0}',response.id);
```